# download audio from youtube c#

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube

I'm trying to download audio from youtube using YoutubeExtractor but if click the button i have information "sequence has no elements". How i can solve it?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(textBox1.Text);

        VideoInfo video = videos.Where(info => info.CanExtractAudio).OrderByDescending(info => info.AudioBitrate).First();

        if (video.RequiresDecryption)
        {
            DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
        }
        AudioDownloader download = new AudioDownloader(video, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\", video.Title + video.AudioExtension));

        download.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that YoutubeExtractor audio extraction currently only works on flash videos right ?

Comment: I want to doing the above code also what type of library required to install in this thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is the call to `First()`. This will throw an exception if your `IEnumerable` contains no items.

To correct this, you need to be sure of two things:

1. The `DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls()` function returns at least 1 item.
2. That at least one item in the `videos` variable has `CanExtractAudio` set to `true`.

Comment: How i can  returns one item using DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(); ?